# Image selector not working well

Tags: android, selector, android-imageview

This is my problem: I have an `ImageView` and I assign a selector to it, so the image have to change when I touch it. The problem is that the image doesn't change.

The selector has a different name than the image sources, so that is not a problem. When I touch the image, the app does an http call, so I think that there is the problem, but I don't know how to solve this.

**Selector xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pat_login_button_pressed"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pat_login_button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pat_login_button"
        android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

**ImageView xml:**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pat_login_button_selector" />
```

Comment: care to show us xml for selector and imageview?

Comment: I just added them to the question, sorry!